# passing dynamic jQuery post to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Hi I need help with the following code. I have searched a number of posts and other sites but to no avail.

This is a stripped down version from a site I'm building which has admin pages with numerous divs that are editable using CKeditor, so serialize is not an option for me(I don't think). I can pass the array to PHP when I hard code the `$.post` indexes and use variables for the content.

This is ok for one page, but I have many. And so when I try to construct the array string as a variable and pass this as a second argument to `$.post`, it fails. Firebug shows json being passed, although the values are in red(the hard coded version is not being identified as json! Just **Index** Value). I believe this is probaly just a syntax issue but I've hit a wall. Can anybody show me the light.

The PHP handler tries various methods of reading the POST.

The dynamic HTML with the js :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery POST Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getElementsByClass(searchClass) {
    var classElements = new Array();
    var node = document;
    var tag = 'div';
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var elsLen = els.length;
    var pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+searchClass+"(\\s|$)");
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
            classElements[j] = els[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return classElements;
}  

function getDivs(){
var divArry = getElementsByClass('editable')
var postElmnts = '';
    for(i=0; i<divArry.length; i++){
        pageName = divArry[i].id;
        pageContent = document.getElementById(pageName).innerHTML;
        //alert(pageName + ': ' + pageContent);//Test if divs are identified properley
        postElmnts= postElmnts + pageName + ': ' + pageContent + ', ';
    };
    postElmnts = postElmnts.slice(0, -2);
    postArry = '{' + postElmnts + '}';
    $.post("process_jQuery_test.php",postArry, function(data){alert(data + 'Original: ' +  postArry);});

}

function grabText(){
    var one = document.getElementById( 'block1' ).innerHTML;
    var two = document.getElementById( 'block2' ).innerHTML;
    var three = document.getElementById( 'block3' ).innerHTML;
    $.post("process_jQuery_test.php", { block1: one, block2: two, block3: three}, function(data){alert( data );} );

}

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onClick="getDivs();">Get Divs dynamically</button>
    <button onClick="grabText();">Grab Text to hard coded index</button>


    <div id="block1" class="editable"><p>This is Block 1 content</p></div>
    <div id="block2" class="editable"><p>This is Block 2 content</p></div>
    <div id="block3" class="editable"><p>This is Block 3 content</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP test handler:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($_POST, true);
$decode = json_decode($_POST,true);
$decodeNstrip = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST),true);

echo "Post 0: ".$_POST[0]."\n\r";

echo "\n\rPost block1: ".$_POST['block1']."\n\r";

echo "\n\rPost loop\n\r";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo $key.': ' .$value."\n\r";
} 

echo "\n\rPost decode: ";
print_r($decode)."\n\r";

echo "\n\rPost decode and strip: ";
print_r($decodeNstrip)."\n\r";

echo "\n\rPost Array: ";
print_r($_POST)."\n\r";

?>
```

Comment: what response is the post getting in firebug?

Comment: You need to start using `var`... It's missing e.g. for your loop variables. Besides that, you are using jQuery. So you have no good reason to use a function such as `getElementsByClass` or `getElementById`

Comment: @ThiefMaster is right you absolutely need to use var in your for loop.  I ran into this recently and it caused _strange errors_ until a colleague pointed that out to me.

Answer (score 3):

The data passing to .post only accepts *`String`* and *`Object`*

*`String`* as in query string, e.g. `year=2000&month=11`

or

*`Object`* in key-value/paired, e.g. `{"year":2000,"month":11}`

Comment: Thanks @W.T. for the note on query strings.  I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In grabText you pass an array/object but in getDivs you're trying to send text.  The text could be formatted as a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), but I prefer this method.

```
function getDivs(){
var divArry = getElementsByClass('editable')
var postElmnts = '';
var msg = {}
    for(i=0; i<divArry.length; i++){
        pageName = divArry[i].id;
        pageContent = document.getElementById(pageName).innerHTML;
        msg[pageName] = pageContent
    };
    $.post("handle.php",msg, function(data){alert(data);});
}
```

Here's the jQuery way of doing it.  I still prefer the more traditional method (plus it's a bit faster).

```
function getDivs(){
    var msg = {}
    $('.editable').each(function(e){
            msg[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).html();
    });

    $.post("handle.php",msg, function(data){alert(data);});
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had tried something that I thought was very similar, but I must have had syntax errors. Thanks also to ThiefMaster, I am a bit of a noob with javascript and jQuery and I do need to brush up on my knowledge. What would replace getElementsByClass in jQuery?

Comment: @Bluebox, I added the jQuery version.

Comment: Sorry FakeRainBrigand, I missed that earlier, this way works a treat as well. Thanks to everyone for your help.